# Rails and access to image asset in js scripts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add some download animated gif in my `application.js` file, but have no idea how to get access to it, I'd like something like:

```
$('.pagination').replaceWith("<%= image_tag('download.gif') %>");
```

but it just outputs `<%= image_tag('download.gif') %>`.

How can I access image asset from .js script?

Answer (score 1):

You should add .erb to the filename. `application.js.erb` and it will work just fine.

Comment: Also see [section 2.3.3 in the Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets).

Comment: I think http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript is also need to be used.